# How to improve performance in recursive method with Loop in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to use memoization pattern in my recursive operation, but something is going wrong.

Below is my method.

```
private Map<String, MyDTO> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void searchRecursive(String uuid) {
    if (!map.containsKey(uuid)) {
        MyDTO obj = myClient.getMyObject(uuid);

        if("one".equals(obj.getType()) || "two".equals(obj.getType())){
            if(Objects.nonNull(obj.getChildren())){
                obj.getChildren().forEach(child -> searchRecursive(child.getId()));
            }
        } else if("three".equals(obj.getType())) {
            map.put(uuid, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to improve the performance of this operation!

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: And the problem is ? Performance only ? should go to codereview

Comment: Yes, only performance

Comment: Obvious things are remove the repeated calls `getType()`, `getChildren()` (and store the results in a variable) - not likely to save a lot, but even if it doesn't help performance it will make the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

I think as @John3136 said, getType(), getChildren() called more than one time, better to create a reference and reduce call time for those methods.

I'm guessing the obj you are trying to search is like a graph or tree, so I think you can try to convert to iterate the child use the BFS method (Queue like data structure), that would be better.

Comment: I already tried Breadth First Search (BFS) and Depth First Search (DFS) :(

 I think the most hard problem here is because Java does not have TCO (Tail Call Optimization). I will try to implement something manually like in this article: https://blog.knoldus.com/tail-recursion-in-java-8/

Comment: Tail call optimization only works when you do the recursive call at the tail. You're doing *n* recursive calls, one for each child of the object, so you would not benefit from tail call optimization even if the language supported that.